# Modify the height of Bootstrap Carousel control?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, carousel

The blue section of the following image shows the triggering area of the bootstrap carousel. I took the screenshot from the [bootstrap doc](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/carousel/#with-controls).

[image]

I would like to modify the height of the triggering region (e.g. From 100% of the carousel height to 50%). May I know how can I modify it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this, just modify the properties of `.carousel-control-prev` and `.carousel-control-prev` in the CSS.

```css
.carousel-control-prev,
.carousel-control-next {
  height: 25%;
  top: 37.5%;
};
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide my-4" data-ride="carousel">
          <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
          </ol>
          <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
              <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/900x350" alt="First slide">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/900x350" alt="Second slide">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/900x350" alt="Third slide">
            </div>
          </div>
          <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
          </a>
          <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

I have no idea why the `top` property could not override in the demo. But it works in my project.